Integral of time-changed Brownian motion
I am trying to solve the following integral with $a>0$ and $W_t$ a Brownian motion:
$$I(t) := \int_0^t\,a\,e^{a\tau}\,W_\tau\,\text d\tau, $$
already seen e.g. here. I proceeded by first applying stochastic integration by parts, hoping to get some Ito integral I can work over:
$$ I(t) = e^{at} W_t - \int_0^t\,e^{a\tau}\,\text dW_\tau = e^{at} W_t - J(t).$$
$J(t)$ appears in the solution usually given to the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE, and on Wikipedia they even use some heuristics over the solution to obtain an explicit form for what corresponds to my $J(t)$.
My question is, are there ways to prove it by directly solving $J(t)$?

What do you mean by "solving the integral" or "solving $J(t)$"?

Sorry, bad wording, I mean computing the closed form of $J(t)$.

There is none. $\phantom.$

To clarify what you found in Wikipedia: If $T_t$ is the inverse function of the strictly increasing function $S_t=\int_0^te^{2a\tau},d\tau=\frac{e^{2at}-1}{2a}$ then $J(T_t)$ is a martingale with quadratic variation $t$ hence, by Levy's theorem a BM. Let's call it $B_t,.$ Then $B_{S_t}$ is an "explicit" representation of $J(t),.$ This is a bit of cheating because we did never explicitly calculate $J(T_t)$ fully.

I am not sure honestly, I found that explanation a bit unclear. Instead, I randomly found out about time-changed Brownian motions, e.g. here that is still noylt a direct way to compute the integral, but at least convinces me.
